# Kivy - Saving object's values changed in Popup, so that after closing it, when I open the popup again it opens with new values

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to change some button labels of a class in a popup and retain the new label after reopening the popup. If you run my app, you can see that after pressing "Press me" button, a popup appears with a button with a label "Default", after pressing on it, it changes the label to "New". I want to be able to close the popup, press the "Press me" button and see the button in a popup with a label "New".

My .py file

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import time

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
Window.size = (800, 480)

class MyGrid(Widget):
    def btn(self):
        show_popup(T, "Window")


class T(FloatLayout):
    pass

def show_popup(tab, name): 
    show = tab()
    popupWindow = Popup(title = name, content = show, size_hint = (None,None), size = (800,384), auto_dismiss = True)
    popupWindow.open()
    return popupWindow

class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

my .kv file

```
<MyGrid>    
    Button:
        text: "Press me"
        on_press: root.btn()


<T>:
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        text: "Default"
        on_press: self.text = "New"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can do it, is by keeping a reference to the popup.
The `py` side:

```py
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
Window.size = (800, 480)


class MyGrid(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.popupWindow = Popup(content=T(), size_hint=(None, None),
                                 size=(800, 384), auto_dismiss=True)

    def btn(self):
        self.show_popup("Window")

    def show_popup(self, name):
        self.popupWindow.title = name
        self.popupWindow.open()


class T(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```